# Ctrl + mousewheel zoom not working in Chrome and Opera with some WP themes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome, opera

I'm trying to figure out why zooming shortcut (Ctrl + mouse wheel) doesn't work with some WordPress themes in Chrome and Opera browsers, but works fine in Firefox and IE.

For example, http://15zine.cubellthemes.com/ has this issue, while, for example, http://souffle.mothemes.com/ does not.

I suspect there might be some JS capturing the hotkey, but that's just a wild guess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can be disabled by CSS or JavaScript.
In CSS it would look like this:

```
zoom: reset;
```

However its difficult to say how they made it, but this would be one option.

Comment: Thanks @karl-hofmann. The weird thing is that zooming with Ctrl+ and Ctrl- works fine. Zooming from browser menu also works fine. It's only Ctrl and mouse wheel that doesn't work. I contacted the theme author and he said he doesn't know why this happens, so I doubt they did it on purpose.